# Undefined / Uninitialized default values in a class

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined

Let's suppose you have this class:

```
class A
{
public:
  A () {}
  A (double val) : m_val(val) {}
  ~A () {}
private:
  double m_val;
};
```

Once I create an instance of A, how can I check if m_val has been initialized/defined?
Put it in other words, is there a way to know if m_val has been initialized/defined or not? Something along the lines of the `defined` operator in Python, I suppose. (But correct me if I'm wrong.)

I thought of modifying the class and the c-tors the following way:

```
class A
{
public:
  A () : defined(false) {}
  A (double val) : m_val(val), defined(true) {}
  ~A () {}
private:
  double m_val;
  bool defined;
};
```

How do you rate this solution? Any suggestion?

TIA,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set a sensible default value in the default constructor, otherwise its value is undefined. Which basically means it will be a random value -- could be 0, NaN, or 2835.23098 -- no way to tell unless you set it explicitly.

```
class A
{
public:
  A () : m_val(0.0) {}
  A (double val) : m_val(val) {}
  ~A () {}
private:
  double m_val;
};
```

Comment: `NaN` would be a good value to me, since it is the only value that couldn't be set.
But, how would you test a variable if it's `NaN`?

Comment: @Jir: `<cmath>` defines `isnan()`. Edit: Actually now I'm not entirely sure where and how it gets defined in C++ (I'm more of a C person myself)... you can always fall back to `value != value` which is only true for floating point values when they're NaN.

Comment: numeric_limits will give you slightly more detail on assigning and checking NaNs and infinities (though you wont need half the checks if you know you are using ieee 754)

Comment: Great! Including `<cmath>` I can now both initialize variables as `NaN`s and check them by means of `isnan()`. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should just initialize your member variables in all constructors, at least with a sensible default value:

```
A () : m_val(0.0) {}
A (double val) : m_val(val) {}
```

I don't see any benefit in retaining a garbage value in your variables (unless you plan to use them as a very crude random number generator - just kidding :-). Such garbage values and extra flags complicate the code, and would always require programmer attention to avoid bugs - and as we are humans, our attention sometimes slips...

Comment: Well, my attention slips particularly easily! :P

Thanks for your comment, I'll avoid let values uninitialized.